# When is it bad to store a user setting or information in the main users table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am still expanding and developing my app.

i currently have a user table with 35 columns. I searched about my question but i am still kinda confused if i am doing it right or wrong. Some say User table other say do relationships.

In the User table except id, username, email and password i also store real name, full address, age, profile image name, country, social urls, premium account(on/off) etc. that every user have

In my app every user has a profile page for which i query the user table to see if user exist or not by username (unique) and if yes i am getting what i want from the User table instead of joining and doing relationship tables etc.

Should i keep it as is or is better to split User table into relations ex. user_details (bio, image name, country etc.) and user_settings (premium, email notification etc.)?

I have relations for other parts of my app but u i can't seem to understand why some prefer to do a relationship table to store a user country and other relevant information. Any thought will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer, this is a design question and your design should reflect your own business requirements.

Comment: 35 columns is acceptable, the point I would make is that you should start splitting info into new tables whenever it is necesary. In your example I would maybe store "social urls" in another table with a 1-N relationship and that's it. That's because a user can have many social url's

Comment: Are any of the tables "big" (eg, bio, picture)?  Rapidly changing (Likes)?

Comment: None of the tables are big yet in terms of users but yes i store in the user table a picture name, bio. Generally info that i use for profile viewing. As for social links those are fixed so a user can not add more at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every user only has one of each of these data items, then the only reason I see to break it out would be for performance. Like if you have 50k of data crammed into every user record, and 90% of the time the only thing you use is name and password, then this could slow down operations that operate on these records.

In general, I think it's a bad idea to denormalize a database for performance reasons unless you have found that in actual practice there is a performance problem, or there is good reason to believe there will be one. A lot of databases get badly hacked up for "performance improvements" that are unnecessary or that don't really improve performance.

I'm sometimes tempted to break up a record for human comprehension reasons, to cut down on clutter. Yes, it's easier to grasp what's in a record if there are fewer fields. But then you have to know that there are these other "attached" records, and when you do care about them if you have to drag in two records. So generally I think it's a bad idea, but I wouldn't rule it out.

Comment: I think as my user database is low i should not split into relationships yet then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you should separate a lot of those thata in conected tables (if your table is going to have a lot of records).

For example, you should have one more table for address information and one more for contacts information (email, phone, fax etc.) so you can keep history of user changes inside those tables and to keep your memory low if you are going to need only primitive data from a user (id, username, name), so you don't have to load all of it from one table.

The other settings (like active/inactive, blocked, some user preferences) that you do not need to have history of, you can keep in users table for easier access.